# How do I reset the image on a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

I've searched around on the Internet and couldn't seem to find a way to remove the image I placed on a button. I was wondering if there is a way to remove the image but keep the button or any other simple quick fix. Here's some of my code for reference.

```
def breakcup():
    if firstroom.cupnotbroken:
        messagebutton.config(text="You broke the cup, and the key was inside the cup.")
        cup.config(image=photo4)
        firstroom.cupnotbroken=False
    else:
        cup.config(image=None, state=DISABLED)
        messagebutton.config(text="You picked up the key")
        firstroom.keynotfound=False
```

Obviously, `image=None` does not work, but it was the closest thing I could find as a solution.

```
root = Toplevel(bob)
root.geometry("640x360+200+250")
root.resizable(0, 0)
app = Room1(root)
```

The windows are made using the `Toplevel(parent)` function. Just to clarify.

Comment: All the variables you see in the code are all declared. Please do not comment me about syntax. It all works.

Comment: Just a guess, but it is possible that `image=None` is the default parameter value, meaning ignore that parameter. You might try creating a "null" image, and doing cup.config() with that.

Comment: Yes, I knew that `image=None` worked like that, but could you give an example of how I could create a null image?

Comment: How did you create `photo4`? Just create an image of the same size, but make it just a solid color.

Comment: I'd recommend a transparent image instead of a solid color. You can make one with something like Photoshop or the GIMP. If you prefer, you could also delete all references to the image with `del photo4`, at which point the image will disappear from the `Label`. However, I'd go with the transparent image.

Comment: What do you mean "obviously, image=None does not work"? Why do you think it doesn't work? That is exactly how you remove an image from a button.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I think it doesn't work because it doesn't. It does not disappear from the button.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The problem with the transparent image is that a disabled image becomes a checkerboard pattern of picture and background to show that it is disabled. I just don't want it to still be able to be pressed after the key is picked up.

Comment: @Markku K. It worked! I also had to change the background to match the color, but it ended up fitting in. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with Tkinter. From my experimentation it seems safe to set the image to an empty string rather than `None`:

```
messagebutton.configure(image="")
```

This works because in the underlying tcl/tk interpreter "everything is a string". That is, the tcl equivalent to `None` is `""`. When you specify an empty string, Tkinter passes that empty string to tcl, and tcl interprets it as "no image".